# Is there a way to hide "button" page when a "FAQ" is opened with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new in code writing. I need help in writing a js code to hide "request a demo" button in the menu section whenever the "FAQ" page is opened. I add an event listener to my function which actually remove the button at a click on the "FAQ" just that, but when the "FAQ" page finish reloading the button appears. Here is my code:

```
var btnShow = document.getElementById("menu-item-19711");
var btnHide = document.getElementById("menu-item-19788");
 btnShow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    btnHide.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't have persistent state when it changes pages. Does the button reload the page / go to a different page? If so, you may want to look in checking if the path is equal to the FAQ page (`window.location.pathname`)

Comment: The button is a link to a different page, so doesn't reload the page. It is a theme on Wordpress and the button is added.